# How to update price of all products in woocommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have almost 1600 products in my store. I want to increase all the the product of my store double of the current price. And want to give all products a discount of 25% after doubling the price. Doing one by one is actually so lengthy. Is there any way of achieving this once at a time?

Comment: Once at a time? Don't have prices in your store. Have an internal base price, and a global discount on those categories. Check out price is all that matters, which you record per transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to activate this function:

```php
function reduce_all_products_price() {
    $products = wc_get_products(['limit' => -1]);
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $new_full_price = floatval($product->get_regular_price('edit')) * 2;
        $product->set_price($new_full_price);
        $product->set_sale_price($new_full_price * 0.75);
    }
}
```

I'm using the 'sale price' to store the value with discount, because i think it makes more sense.
There are several ways to activate your function, but maybe the easiest would be to add a hook to `admin_init` and check for some parameter in URL.

```
add_action('admin_init', function () {
    if (isset($_GET['discount-everybody']) && $_GET['discount-everybody'] == 'true') {
        reduce_all_products_price();
    }
});
```

Then you have to be logged in to wp-admin and access `yoursite.com/wp-admin/index.php?discount-everybody=true`

Be careful not to do this twice.

Comment: *Be careful not to do this twice.* is why it is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, the more complete implementation would be to add a button in admin somewhere, of course some alerts saying 'are you sure???'... but that is not the scope of the question. Feel free to add your suggestion

Comment: Will I follow the steps exactly you shared?

Comment: And will this process work for variable product also?

Comment: Yes it will. You can check each product by `$product->is_type('variable')` if you want

Comment: please make backup befor doing this